# LINQ to SQL auto-generated type for stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].Test
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE ##table
    (
        ID1 int,
        ID2 int
    )

    DECLARE @query varchar(MAX);

    INSERT INTO ##table VALUES(1, 1);

    SELECT * FROM ##table;
END
```

And I try to use it from C# code. I use LINQ to SQL as an O/RM. When I add the procedure to DataBaseContext it says that it can't figure out the return value of this procedure. How to modify the stored procedure so that I can use it with LINQ to SQL.

Note: I need to have **global template table**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try identifying the columns in your select.

```
SELECT ID1, ID2 FROM ##table;
```

Answer (score 5):

for MSSQL use `SET FMTONLY OFF;` at the begining of the proc.  Tells SQL to run the stored proc not to make assumptions, which is the only way I've learned to make LINQ work when using temp tables.

Comment: OK, your answer is GOLD!  Worked like a charm for me :-)